# Code reuse in multiple mvc views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have read this link: https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/view-code-reuse-techniques-in-asp-net-mvc/

I can not use any of those helper ways...

I have to show on multiple mvc sites this string:

1612-1

That is an inquiry number: 16 is the day of month, 12 the month of year and 1 is the database id. I am sure that will not be the final impl but for now we take it as given.

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public List<string> ActionItemDescriptions { get; set; }
        public string InquiryNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Where would you create the InquiryNumber?

If I put it inside the razor view I cant reuse it.

Comment: can you show your view ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems business logic to me , so it belongs in the business layer.

Then, from within your controller you:

- call the business component which returns the inquiry number
- store the number in your view model
- pass the view model to the view.

Comment: busines logic? To me that is presentation logic.

Comment: Calculating an inquiry number is no presentation logic at all. Presentation logic is about presenting data to the user, and everything about UI manipulation, but not calculating it. It's something you probably need outside the UI also, for example in background processes etc.

Comment: Anyway, if according to you this is not business logic, the principle stays the same: you have it calculated by a component which is called from the controller.

Comment: and what is this component named in the mvc architecture?

Comment: MVC is: (C)ontrollers that construct ViewModels (based on the (M)odel) and pass them to the (V)iews. The business component is part of the (M)odel, which is a rich model that contains data and business logic. Typically I use a separate (physical or logical) layer with service components that are called from within the controllers. In your case you could just create a folder 'Services', and a class like 'InquiryService' or something; in which you add a method to return the inquiry number, and consume this method from your controller. You can inject components with dependency injection.

Comment: It was more a rethorical question but you answered what I already knew: service. The problem I see here as soon I introduce a service and put multiple calls in there then I need DTO`s to return to controllers and then my controllers look like viewmodels concerning the structure. I dont like this overhead and my boss neither...

Comment: It's not overhead, it's best practice. But by all means, feel free to do whatever you want :)

Comment: I correct a typo: "...then my dto`s look like viewmodels..."

Comment: No, you map your dto's to view models.

Comment: yes but both objects DTO / VM has the same structure. Its overhead.

Comment: It's not. One day you may understand why, if you learn about abstraction :) Good luck anyway.

Comment: I understand the time and pressure of the market and my boss. Thats weights more than abstraction ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could get an inquiry number, without using a helper, is this:

In a controller, have the following action method:

```
public ActionResult GetInquiryNumber()
{
    // TODO : The code to get the inquiry number.
    return Content("1612-1");
}
```

You can then call that method in any view you like, using the following:

`@{ Html.RenderAction("GetInquiryNumber", "Home"); }`

Obviously you will need to come up with your own method, and controller, names.

This isn't the ideal way of passing data to a view (using a viewmodel is preferable), but the above approach is an option to you.